# lowering faces in a mesh

Tags: mesh, faces

I'm attempting to lower a face with out causing a edge to be pulled down with it how can this be achieved...

I have tried extruding and moving the face downwards, but when I delete the faces that are left I'm still left with the edges present messing up the mesh...

[image]

[image]

I wish to avoid the second image

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8639/intrude-faces-instead-of-extruding

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/extruding-inwards-leaves-vertices-alone or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51729/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-cut-extrude-inward-extrude